# Why do some flags have a red background?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, deleted-answers, flag-history

Recently I noticed that some of my flags have a red like background while others do not.

<kbd>[image: Flags]</kbd>

Here you can see that the third item has a title with a red like background while the others do not. I tried to find a reason for this different color but I could not find one.

At first I though that these question might have been deleted but this turned out not to be the case.
 It also probably has nothing to do with helpful / declined / aged away / disputed as some of them have the red background while others do not.

So why do these flags have a different background color? Is there a specific reason for it?

Just curious :)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It is the UI telling you that the post has been deleted.

Comment: No I just clicked the link on a few of the red flags and some of them still existed while others did not.

Comment: @Roan Link to examples then, with screenshots showing the red background. If it shows as red, it's supposed to be deleted. Are you sure it's not answers that you flagged and are deleted while the question is still there?

Comment: I just checked this. I have a red background, and the [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20326478/convert-word-file-pages-to-jpg-images-using-c-sharp/29986702#29986702) is still there. I would have thought that it was because it had an answer, but [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29826467/what-is-the-best-way-to-structure-password-storing-tables-in-rdbms/29826861#29826861) is not answered and it has a red background too.

Comment: @Roan - Every single one of those does link to a deleted post. Only 10k users can see deleted posts, so if the deleted post is an answer, you will be redirected to the question it was left on. You won't see the deleted answer.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro the question is still there, but the answer no longer is.  The link is supposed to page to the answer if it exists, otherwise it just shows the question.

Comment: Ah right I think I might have mixed up answers and questions

Comment: Well then my issue is resolved thanks everyone!